# Density of rational functions in open Stein

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, several-complex-variables

I repost here, after I tried [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860354/density-of-rational-functions-in-open-stein-sets).

Lately I have been wondering on this problem: if $U \subset \mathbb C^n$ is an open *Stein* and I denote by $\mathcal R(U)$ the set of rational functions on $\mathbb C^n$ whose restriction to $U$ is holomorphic, is it true that the natural inclusion $\mathcal R(U) \to \mathcal H(U)$ is dense? Here $\mathcal H(U)$ denotes the algebra of holomorphic functions on $U$ endowed with the topology of uniform convergence over compacts.

I know that when $n = 1$ this is essentially the content of Runge's approximation theorem, but I didn't find any reference for the several variables case in the literature I know, and I do have problems in extending the proof of the $1$-dimensional case. Namely, the difficulty I encountered is the following: given an open Stein $U$, a compact $K \subset U$, I should provide a uniform approximation of any $f \in \mathcal H(K)$ with rational functions which are holomorphic inside $U$, and all what I can do is to approximate $f$ with rational functions which are holomorphic in a sufficiently small neighbourhood of $K$. In fact, if I am not mistaken, if one can prove this, then one can also prove the density of $\mathcal R(U)$ inside $\mathcal H(U)$ (and in this implication the hypothesis of $U$ being Stein is heavily used, because Stein exhaustions are necessary).

**Remark.** I would like to stress that $\mathcal R(U)$ is the set of *rational* functions and *not* polynomial functions (I am in fact well aware that the problem of understanding Runge domains in higher dimensions is way more complicated than the one-dimensional case).

Comment: What is a Stein?

Comment: For example you can characterize Stein spaces as those complex analytic spaces $X$ such that $\mathrm{H}^1(\mathcal F) = 0$ for every coherent sheaf $\mathcal F$ on $X$.